# Website research tool that shows information about domains (like WHOIS, IP, backlinks, etc.)

Tags: search, internet, web

Looking for a tool that can do the following:

- receive input a domain name (or host name like shop.example.com)
- produce a report for the domain/host for such information as

  - WHOIS
  - IP, IP owner, sites on the same IP
  - check against spam blacklist
  - check against security, malware list
  - link to Internet Archive records
  - list of backlinks to the host
  - common site popularity score such as Google PageRank, Alexa Traffic Rank etc.

All the above information should be fetch from the various sources by the program with no or little user action needed.

The program must be able to combine all the information into a single report.
Report can be in text, doc or html.

The time taken to generate the report is not so important. However if an estimation of the time to generate report for the tool is available, feel free to mention it.

Free or paid are fine.

A Windows GUI program is preferred, but a hosted service is also acceptable.

Comment: It seems that many websites provide this kind of information, please describe why some of the most common ones are not enough for you, so that we can help you better.

Comment: Could you please explain a few things: how do you want the report? What do you mean by PageRank? What do you mean by Alexa? (their rank number maybe?) What do you mean by Internet Archive? (how many snapshots it has perhaps?) What do you mean by backlinks? (Number of backlinks?)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul , sites I seem mostly provide one or some of the information. I have not come across a website that can combine all the information into 1 step and produce a report. If you know of such a site, kindly share the answer.

Comment: @Janekmuric , question updated based on your clarification.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Just one question: How long is the max time it would take to generate a report?

Comment: @Janekmuric: Me? Did you mean to mention the asker? :-)

Comment: Yes, I meant to ask @kenchew

Comment: @Janekmuric updated question to include time.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found any websites or programs that can do what you need, so instead of learning Geography, I made a Python 2.7 program to do it for you.

Big thanks to jgamblin on Github for his opern source blacklist finder script.

```
from pprint import pprint, pformat
from sys import exit, argv
from socket import gethostbyname, gethostbyaddr
from os.path import exists, isdir
from json import dumps
from time import strftime, time
from re import findall
from urllib2 import urlopen, Request, build_opener
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import dns.resolver
from ipwhois import IPWhois

# Code below downloaded from GitHub page:
# https://github.com/jgamblin/isthisipbad/blob/master/isthisipbad.py
# Modified by Janek to fix errors.

def content_test(url, badip):
    """
    Test the content of url's response to see if it contains badip.
        Args:
            url -- the URL to request data from
            badip -- the IP address in question
        Returns:
            Boolean
    """

    try:
        request = Request(url)
        html_content = build_opener().open(request).read()

        matches = findall(badip, html_content)

        return len(matches) == 0
    except Exception, e:
        return False

bls = ["b.barracudacentral.org", "bl.spamcannibal.org", "bl.spamcop.net",
       "blacklist.woody.ch", "cbl.abuseat.org", "cdl.anti-spam.org.cn",
       "combined.abuse.ch", "combined.rbl.msrbl.net", "db.wpbl.info",
       "dnsbl-1.uceprotect.net", "dnsbl-2.uceprotect.net",
       "dnsbl-3.uceprotect.net", "dnsbl.cyberlogic.net",
       "dnsbl.sorbs.net", "drone.abuse.ch", "drone.abuse.ch",
       "duinv.aupads.org", "dul.dnsbl.sorbs.net", "dul.ru",
       "dyna.spamrats.com", "dynip.rothen.com",
       "http.dnsbl.sorbs.net", "images.rbl.msrbl.net",
       "ips.backscatterer.org", "ix.dnsbl.manitu.net",
       "korea.services.net", "misc.dnsbl.sorbs.net",
       "noptr.spamrats.com", "ohps.dnsbl.net.au", "omrs.dnsbl.net.au",
       "orvedb.aupads.org", "osps.dnsbl.net.au", "osrs.dnsbl.net.au",
       "owfs.dnsbl.net.au", "pbl.spamhaus.org", "phishing.rbl.msrbl.net",
       "probes.dnsbl.net.au", "proxy.bl.gweep.ca", "rbl.interserver.net",
       "rdts.dnsbl.net.au", "relays.bl.gweep.ca", "relays.nether.net",
       "residential.block.transip.nl", "ricn.dnsbl.net.au",
       "rmst.dnsbl.net.au", "smtp.dnsbl.sorbs.net",
       "socks.dnsbl.sorbs.net", "spam.abuse.ch", "spam.dnsbl.sorbs.net",
       "spam.rbl.msrbl.net", "spam.spamrats.com", "spamrbl.imp.ch",
       "t3direct.dnsbl.net.au", "tor.dnsbl.sectoor.de",
       "torserver.tor.dnsbl.sectoor.de", "ubl.lashback.com",
       "ubl.unsubscore.com", "virus.rbl.jp", "virus.rbl.msrbl.net",
       "web.dnsbl.sorbs.net", "wormrbl.imp.ch", "xbl.spamhaus.org",
       "zen.spamhaus.org", "zombie.dnsbl.sorbs.net"]

URLS = [
    #TOR
    ('http://torstatus.blutmagie.de/ip_list_exit.php/Tor_ip_list_EXIT.csv',
     'is not a TOR Exit Node',
     'is a TOR Exit Node',
     False),

    #EmergingThreats
    ('http://rules.emergingthreats.net/blockrules/compromised-ips.txt',
     'is not listed on EmergingThreats',
     'is listed on EmergingThreats',
     True),

    #AlienVault
    ('http://reputation.alienvault.com/reputation.data',
     'is not listed on AlienVault',
     'is listed on AlienVault',
     True),

    #BlocklistDE
    ('http://www.blocklist.de/lists/bruteforcelogin.txt',
     'is not listed on BlocklistDE',
     'is listed on BlocklistDE',
     True),

    #Dragon Research Group - SSH
    ('http://dragonresearchgroup.org/insight/sshpwauth.txt',
     'is not listed on Dragon Research Group - SSH',
     'is listed on Dragon Research Group - SSH',
     True),

    #Dragon Research Group - VNC
    ('http://dragonresearchgroup.org/insight/vncprobe.txt',
     'is not listed on Dragon Research Group - VNC',
     'is listed on Dragon Research Group - VNC',
     True),

    #OpenBLock
    ('http://www.openbl.org/lists/date_all.txt',
     'is not listed on OpenBlock',
     'is listed on OpenBlock',
     True),

    #NoThinkMalware
    ('http://www.nothink.org/blacklist/blacklist_malware_http.txt',
     'is not listed on NoThink Malware',
     'is listed on NoThink Malware',
     True),

    #NoThinkSSH
    ('http://www.nothink.org/blacklist/blacklist_ssh_all.txt',
     'is not listed on NoThink SSH',
     'is listed on NoThink SSH',
     True),

    #Feodo
    ('http://rules.emergingthreats.net/blockrules/compromised-ips.txt',
     'is not listed on Feodo',
     'is listed on Feodo',
     True),

    #antispam.imp.ch
    ('http://antispam.imp.ch/spamlist',
     'is not listed on antispam.imp.ch',
     'is listed on antispam.imp.ch',
     True),

    #dshield
    ('http://www.dshield.org/ipsascii.html?limit=10000',
     'is not listed on dshield',
     'is listed on dshield',
     True),

    #malc0de
    ('http://malc0de.com/bl/IP_Blacklist.txt',
     'is not listed on malc0de',
     'is listed on malc0de',
     True),

    #MalWareBytes
    ('http://hosts-file.net/rss.asp',
     'is not listed on MalWareBytes',
     'is listed on MalWareBytes',
     True)]

def blacklist(badip):
    BAD = 0
    GOOD = 0

    for url, succ, fail, mal in URLS:
        test = content_test(url, badip)
        if test == True:
            GOOD = GOOD + 1
        elif test == False:
            BAD = BAD + 1

    BAD = BAD
    GOOD = GOOD

    for bl in bls:
        try:
                my_resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
                query = '.'.join(reversed(str(badip).split("."))) + "." + bl
                my_resolver.timeout = 5
                my_resolver.lifetime = 5
                answers = my_resolver.query(query, "A")
                answer_txt = my_resolver.query(query, "TXT")
                BAD = BAD + 1

        except dns.resolver.NXDOMAIN:
            GOOD = GOOD + 1

        except dns.resolver.Timeout:
            pass

        except dns.resolver.NoNameservers:
            pass

        except dns.resolver.NoAnswer:
           pass

    return str(BAD) + "/" + str(BAD+GOOD)

# Code ABOVE downloaded from GitHub page:
# https://github.com/jgamblin/isthisipbad/blob/master/isthisipbad.py
# Modified by Janek to fix errors.  

def get_rank(domain_to_query):
    result = {'Global':'', "Country":''}
    url = "http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/" + domain_to_query
    page = urlopen(url).read()
    soup = bs(page, "html.parser")
    for span in soup.find_all('span'):
        if span.has_attr("class"):
            if "globleRank" in span["class"]:
                for strong in span.find_all("strong"):
                    if strong.has_attr("class"):
                        if "metrics-data" in strong["class"]:
                            result['Global'] = strong.text.replace("\n", "").replace(" ", "")
            if "countryRank" in span["class"]:
                image = span.find_all("img")
                for img in image:
                    if img.has_attr("title"):
                        country = img["title"]
                for strong in span.find_all("strong"):
                    if strong.has_attr("class"):
                        if "metrics-data" in strong["class"]:
                            result["Country"] = country + ": " + strong.text.replace("\n", "").replace(" ", "")
    return result

def parseData(ip, data, whdata, blk, rank, tim, iphost):
    whois = whdata["nets"]
    dnet = data["network"]
    ob = data["objects"]
    curtime = strftime("%d %B %Y %H:%M:%S")

    if curtime[0] == "0":
        curtime = curtime[1:]

    timee = str(tim).split(".")[0] + "." + str(tim).split(".")[1][:2]
    outStr = "WARNING: Data below may be inaccurate\nTarget: " + ip + "\nGenerated: " + curtime + "\nTime took to generate: " + timee + " seconds" + "\n\n"

    outStr += "IP host: " + iphost + "\n\n"

    outStr += "Blacklist: " + blk + "\n\n"
    outStr += "Archive: http://web.archive.org/web/*/" + iphost + "\n"
    outStr += "Global Alexa rank: " + rank["Global"] + "\n"
    outStr += "Country Alexa rank: "+ rank["Country"] + "\n\n"


    outStr += "Legacy Whois:\n"
    net = 1
    for i in whois:
        outStr += "  Network " + str(net) + ":\n"
        try:
            outStr += "    IP: " + str(whdata["query"]) + "\n"
        except:
            outStr += "    IP: Not found\n"
        try:
            outStr += "    Name: " + str(i["name"]) + "\n"
        except:
            outStr += "    Name: Not found\n"
        try:
            outStr += "    Abuse E-mails: " + str(i["abuse_emails"]) + "\n"
        except:
            outStr += "    Abuse E-mails: Not found\n"
        try:
            outStr += "    Adress: " + str(i["adress"]) + "\n"
        except:
            outStr += "    Adress: Not found\n"
        try:
            outStr += "    Country: " + str(i["country"]) + "\n"
        except:
            outStr += "    Country: Not found\n"
        try:
            outStr += "    City: " + str(i["city"]) + "\n"
        except:
            outStr += "    City: Not found\n"
        try:
            outStr += "    Postal code: " + str(i["postal_code"]) + "\n"
        except:
            outStr += "    Postal code: Not found\n"
        try:
            outStr += "    Created: " + str(i["created"]) + "\n"
        except:
            outStr += "    Created: Not found\n"
        try:
            outStr += "    Description: " + str(i["description"]) + "\n"
        except:
            outStr += "    Description: Not found\n"
        try:
            outStr += "    Handle: " + str(i["handle"]) + "\n"
        except:
            outStr += "    Handle: Not found\n"
        try:
            outStr += "    Misc E-mails: " + str(i["misc_emails"]) + "\n"
        except:
            outStr += "    Misc E-mails: Not found\n"
        try:
            outStr += "    IP range: " + str(i["range"]) + "\n"
        except:
            outStr += "    IP range: Not found\n"
        try:
            outStr += "    State: " + str(i["state"]) + "\n"
        except:
            outStr += "    State: Not found\n"
        try:
            outStr += "    Tech E-mails: " + str(i["tech_emails"]) + "\n"
        except:
            outStr += "    Tech E-mails: Not found\n"
        try:
            outStr += "    Updated: " + str(i["updated"]) + "\n\n"
        except:
            outStr += "    Updated: Not found\n\n"

        net += 1

    outStr += "\nRDAP (HTTP) Whois:\n"

    try:
        outStr += "  Name: " + str(dnet["name"]) + "\n"
    except:
        outStr += "  Name: Not found\n"
    try:
        outStr += "  Start adress: " + str(dnet["start_adress"]) + "\n"
    except:
        outStr += "  Start adress: Not found\n"
    try:
        outStr += "  End adress: " + str(dnet["end_adress"]) + "\n"
    except:
        outStr += "  End adress: Not found\n"
    try:
        outStr += "  IP verion: " + str(dnet["ip_versoin"]) + "\n"
    except:
        outStr += "  IP version: Not found\n"

    outStr += "  Events:\n"

    e = 1
    for i in dnet["events"]:
        outStr += "    Event " + str(e) + ":\n"
        try:
            outStr += "      Action: " + str(i["action"]) + "\n"
        except:
            outStr += "      Action: Not found\n"
        try:
            outStr += "      Actor: " + str(i["actor"]) + "\n"
        except:
            outStr += "      Actor: Not found\n"
        try:
            outStr += "      Timestamp: " + str(i["timestamp"]) + "\n"
        except:
            outStr += "      Timestamp: Not found\n"

        e += 1

    outStr += "\n  Objects:\n"
    for i in ob:
        z = ob[i]["contact"]
        outStr += "    " + str(i) + ":\n"
        try:
            outStr += "      Name: " + str(z["name"]) + "\n"
        except:
            outStr += "      Name: Not found\n"
        try:
            outStr += "      E-mail: " + str(z["email"][0]["value"]) + "\n"
        except:
            outStr += "      E-mail: Not found\n"
        try:
            outStr += "      Kind: " + str(z["kind"]) + "\n"
        except:
            outStr += "      Kind: Not found\n"
        try:
            outStr += "      Phone: " + str(z["phone"][0]["value"]) + "\n"
        except:
            outStr += "      Phone: Not found\n"
        try:
            outStr += "      Title: " + str(z["title"]) + "\n"

        except:
            outStr += "      Title: Not found\n"
        try:
            outStr += "      Links: "
        except:
            outStr += "      Links: Not found\n"

        if ob[i]["links"]:
            if not len(ob[i]["links"]) == 0:
                for j in ob[i]["links"]:
                    outStr += str(j).replace("\n", " ")
                    outStr += "  "
        else:
            outStr += "Not found"

        outStr += "\n      Contact: "
        if z["address"]:
            for j in z["address"]:
                outStr += str(j["value"].replace("\n", ", "))

        else:
            outStr += "Not found"
        outStr += "\n\n"
    return outStr

def getData(ip):
    obj = IPWhois(ip)
    results = obj.lookup_rdap(depth=1)
    return results

def whgetData(ip):
    obj = IPWhois(ip)
    results = obj.lookup()
    return results

def showHelp():
    name = argv[0].replace("\\","/").split("/")[-1]
    print("""
Simple website report (Whois) generator
Usage:
    %s website [-json]
            [-file <file>]
            [-raw]

Arguments:
    website       Website IPv4 or domain
    -json         Convert output to json 
    -file         Save output to a file
    -raw          Output full Whois lookup in raw format

""" % name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = argv

    if len(args) < 2:
        print("Too few arguments!")
        showHelp()
        exit(1)

    if len(args) > 5:
        print("Too many arguments!")
        showHelp()
        exit(1)

    allowedArgs = ["-file", "-json", "-raw"]
    noLast = ["-file"]

    b = 2
    for i in args[2:]:
        if i not in allowedArgs and args[b-1] not in noLast:
            print("Invalid option (%s)" % i)
            showHelp()
            exit(1)
        b += 1

    for i in args[2:]:
        if args.count(i) > 1 and i in allowedArgs:
            print("Option appearing more then once (%s)" % i)
            showHelp()
            exit(1)

    if args[-1] in noLast:
        print("Option has no arguments (%s)" % args[-1])
        showHelp()
        exit(1)

    if "-json" in args and "-raw" in args:
        print("Can't use -json and -raw in the same time")
        showHelp()
        exit(1)

    rawIP = args[1]
    if rawIP.replace(".","").isdigit() == True:
        ip = rawIP
    else:
        ip = gethostbyname(rawIP)

    if "-file" in args:
        filename = args[args.index("-file") + 1]
        if exists(filename) == True:
            print("File already exists (%s)" % filename) 
            showHelp()
            exit(1)

        directory = "/".join(filename.replace("\\","/").split("/")[0:-1])

        if len(directory) > 0 and isdir(directory) == False:
            print("Directory does not exist (%s)" % directory) 
            showHelp()
            exit(1)

        fileOn = True
    else:
        fileOn = False

    t1 = time()
    data = getData(ip)
    whdata = whgetData(ip)
    blk = blacklist(ip)

    if rawIP.replace(".","").isdigit() == True:
        try:
            iphost = gethostbyaddr(ip)
        except:
            iphost = "Not found"
    else:
        iphost = rawIP

    rank = get_rank(iphost)
    t2 = time()

    t = t2-t1
    if "-file" not in args:
        if "-json" in args:
            all = {"http_whois":data, "legacy_whois":whdata, "blacklist":blk, "rank":rank, "time":t}
            print(dumps(all, ensure_ascii=False) + "\n")
            exit(0)

        elif "-raw" in args:
            all = {"http_whois":data, "legacy_whois":whdata, "blacklist":blk, "rank":rank, "time":t}
            pprint(all)
            exit(0)

        else:
            parsed = parseData(ip, data, whdata, blk, rank, t, iphost)
            print(parsed)
            exit(0)

    else:
        if "-json" in args:
            all = {"http_whois":data, "legacy_whois":whdata, "blacklist":blk, "rank":rank, "time":t}
            forWrite = dumps(all, ensure_ascii=False) + "\n"
            f = open(filename,"w")
            f.write(forWrite)
            f.close()
            print("File created!")
            exit(0)

        elif "-raw" in args:
            all = {"http_whois":data, "legacy_whois":whdata, "blacklist":blk, "rank":rank, "time":t}
            forWrite = pformat(all)
            f = open(filename,"w")
            f.write(forWrite)
            f.close()
            print("File created!")
            exit(0)

        else:
            parsed = parseData(ip, data, whdata, blk, rank, t, iphost)
            forWrite = parsed
            f = open(filename,"w")
            f.write(forWrite)
            f.close()
            print("File created!")
            exit(0)
```

## What to do:

1. Download Python 2.7.x
2. Install it (check the "Add python.exe to Path" checkbox when installing)
3. Copy and paste the code above into a file called `yournamehere.py`
4. Now you can run the program from `cmd` with the folowing query:

`python yournamehere.py www.google.com`

NOTE: You have to install the folowing libraries for the code to work `dnspython`, `bs4`, `ipwhois`

To install them go to cmd and type in line by line:

```
pip install dnspython
pip install ipwhois
pip install bs4
```

## Help:

```
Simple website report (Whois) generator
Usage:
        netreport.py website [-json]
                        [-file <file>]
                        [-raw]

Arguments:
        website           Website IPv4 or domain
        -json             Convert output to json
        -file             Save output to a file
        -raw          Output full Whois lookup in raw format
```

If you want to format the output full report in a Pythonic dictionary use `-raw.

If you want to format the output in json use "-json".

`-raw` and `-json` cannot be used in the same time.

If you want to save the output to a file use `-file`

## Examples:

```
python yournamehere.py www.google.com
python yournamehere.py www.google.com -json
python yournamehere.py www.google.com -file myreport.txt
python yournamehere.py www.google.com -raw -file myfile.txt
python yournamehere.py www.google.com -file C:\Users\Jan\Desktop\file.txt
```

## Speed:

It's pretty slow. For `www.google.com` it takes ~30 seconds to generate the report. My internet is also slow: 4Mbps Down, 0.5 Mbps Up (yes, really slow)

Comment: Not quite what I need but definitely deserve an upvote for the (huge!) effort to put together the code and the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Well, that's all I got. Anyways I'm not sure what you're looking for because the program does everything on your list besides backlinks. I have to learn Geography now. (and this is the best website I could find to do what you need but it's missing a lot of the info https://centralops.net/co/DomainDossier.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for taking time to put the answer together. Much appreciated.